# cannot start any docker containers sometime anymore

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Sometimes after:

- a container has created a lot of threads
- I restarted a container several time because it crashed

it got when starting (`docker-composer up`) an arbitrary container:

```
ERROR: for container_name Cannot start service container_name: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:385: applying cgroup configuration for process caused: mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/99dec670f659c8411b960d99bbafc13f0429e178b1ea8417e6cfc8d56182291b: permission denied: unknown
```

There is neither a high load (<100) in number of thread not in memory usage of the server reported by ``` docker stats``or ``` htop`.

The problem can not be fixed by restarting the docker process (`docker.service` and `docker.socket`) - but by restarting the (virtual) machine.
Also after sometime (2 days / weekend) of not doing anything on the server (but keep other containers running) the problem disappears.

Comment: Problem seems to be cause when the maximum number of allowed threads is exceeded. On virtual machines this is often limited - e,g. to only 1100. If in addition the operating system is allowing only 30 % of that, docker reports that error.

https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/841.

Comment: Unfortunate increasing the limit mentioned above did not help.

Comment: Have the same problem. Do you found a solution?